# Logback, there are no log files at all(RollingFileAppender and SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, logging, logback

Have a problem with logback. I've tried to log my actions, want to write all logs to file, but there are no logs at all after start of my application

logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE-LOGGER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>log/application.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>log/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log%i</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.test.application" level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-LOGGER"/>
    </logger>
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-LOGGER"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

service.java

```
 static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestClass.class);
public List<Items> getAll(){
    LOG.info("hi, info!!!!!");
    LOG.error("hi, error!!!!!");
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

expect that logs will be in the log file

Comment: I have provided answer, can you check ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy logback dependency

Comment: Why the scope of logback dependency is test? Remove this if you do not run service.java from a junit-test

Comment: Now logs disappeared from console, but there are no files in logs folder

Comment: Try an absolute path. I think you are looking into a wrong directory.

Comment: Directory was right, I found an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentaly I found an issue
I delete file from *logback.xml* and started to receive logs in console and found next interesting rows:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.26/slf4j-simple-1.7.26.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@100454a1 - A "ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy" object is not assignable to a "ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingPolicy" variable.
```

To fix this issue you need to do next steps:

- delete slf4j dependencies
- rename **SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy** to
  **SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy**